# Como fazer um tratamento de erros para pesquisa não encontrada em ASP.NET API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-request

O retorno fora do bloco try-catch me retorna um array vazio, mas o que eu deveria colocar ali para que me retornasse alguma mensagem de erro no status da requisição da API? Retirar o IEnumerable e trocar por um ActionResult não é uma opção pois preciso retornar uma lista de objetos que possuem determinada chave estrangeira.

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IEnumerable<Project> Get(int id)
    {
            try
            {
                return _acess.GetCourse(id);
            }
            catch (DataException ex)
            {
                BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            return _acess.GetCourse(id);
        }
            
    }
```

Comment: Pelo que parece vc está no controller A retornando uma lista de itens B que pertencem a A. Certo? Que erro vc quer retornar? Quando A não existir ou quando não tiver nenhum item B em A?

Comment: Ambas opções, na verdade. Não sei pelo que eu deveria substituir o segundo return.

Comment: Viu editar a resposta logo mais. Mas... O 2o return? Os 2 não sao iguais?

Comment: Um outro detalhe, que tipo de erro vc espera? Vc pretende retornar uma mensagem de erro no body? Se for isso, não é usual fazer isso em APIs, pois há os http status code para dar informações sobre o retorno. Um exemplo onde faz sentido retornar o erro no body é para validações, o que não é o caso.

Comment: Então neste caso é correto retornar o array vazio mesmo? Não tenho muito conhecimento ainda acerca do assunto.

Comment: Isso dá um longo debate, mesmo estando especificado no RFC 2616. Eu, particularmente, costumo retornar 404 no 1o caso (A não existe) e 2xx com lista vazia no 2o caso (quando A não tem nenhum B). Neste 2o caso já vi pessoas defenderem o retornar 404.

Comment: o que retorna: `return _acess.GetCourse(id);`?  tem como colocar o código desse método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato o `ActionResult` não funciona com este seu retorno, mas se deixar de usar uma interface, já poderá ser usado.

Este seu método poderia ser:

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<List<Project>> Get(int id)
  => _acess.GetCourse(id)?.ToList();
```

**Update para atender aos comentários da pergunta**

Segundo as especificações do [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), o status 404 deve ser retornado quando a rota solicitada não existir.

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

A especificação é aberta a interpretações, mas no meu ponto de vista, bem como o que mais encontro, no caso de não encontrar elementos que satisfaçam uma pesquisa é preferível utilizar os status 200 (OK) ou 204 (No Content).

Pessoalmente, prefiro a utilização do status 200 com uma lista vazia (`[]` no body) por ser mais fácil tratar tanto o envio do resultado (sua API) quanto o tratamento do resultado (o que os clientes da API precisam fazer).

Transportando isso para o seu caso, a rota deste endpoint deveria ser algo como `/seucontrolador/{id}/filho`, indicando que serão retornados elementos que dependem de um registro "pai". Retorna-se 404 quando o elemento pai não existir, uma vez que a rota `/seucontrolador/{id}/*` de fato não existe. Nos demais casos, poderia-se retornar 200 ou 204 (devendo ser documentado) e os clientes da api deverão saber tratar o retorno.

Exemplo de código para atingir o objetivo acima:

```cs
[HttpGet("/seucontrolador/{id}/filho")]
public ActionResult<List<Project>> GetFilhos(int id)
{
    // verifica se objeto pai existe
    // ex: if (_acess.Get(id) == null)
    // => melhor usar um método específico, uma vez que não é preciso usar o objeto retornado
    if (false)
    {
        return this.NotFound();
    }

    // Sempre retorna uma lista, mesmo que GetCourse(id) seja null
    return _acess.GetCourse(id)?.ToList() ?? new List<Project>();
}
```

Seguindo o template do próprio asp.net core, para fornecer exemplos dos diferentes tipos de retorno.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // Retorna uma lista e status 200 (OK)
        [HttpGet("lista")]
        public ActionResult<List<WeatherForecast>> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
                .Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                })
                .ToList();
        }

        // Retorna uma lista vazia e status 200 (OK)
        [HttpGet("listavazia")]
        public ActionResult<List<WeatherForecast>> GetListaVazia()
        {
            return new List<WeatherForecast>();
        }

        // Retorna status 204 (No Content)
        [HttpGet("null")]
        public ActionResult<List<WeatherForecast>> GetNull()
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Retorna status 404 (Not Found)
        [HttpGet("notfound")]
        public ActionResult<List<WeatherForecast>> GetNotFOund()
        {
            return this.NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo retorno de array vazio, assim como no meu código.

Comment: Como está a sua GetCourse? Se você quer retornar um 404, você terá que refatorar algumas coisas, por exemplo vc pode lançar uma exceção no método GetCourse e capturá-la na sua controller.